# HD rapid seeks never ends

Tags: 18.04

Starts  rapid track seeking as soon as user is clicked at about 10 to 20 seeks a second. Does not slow down a running program as the running program has priority.  It might not happen for days but when it does start it never ends.
Restarting Ubuntu has no effect it just restarts rapid seeking.
ps ax shows kworker active, but that maybe expected anyway.
It will eventually wear out the Hard drive.

Comment: I have discovered that before switchon if I unplug the ethernet cable from the modem, the problem restarts, but when I plug the ethernet back into the modem it stops so far for all this session !

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app SMART Data & Tests window. Also show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: While the problem is active HTOP shows that the function /usr/lib/snapd/snapd is almost the only displayed activity.

Comment: Please answer the questions that I asked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Comment: I don't understand. You asked for help. I asked for some information so I could help. You haven't provided the information. Do you want the help or not? Third request.